# Is a pendulum doing work without an external force?

Tags: kinetic-theory

A force is used to lift a pendulum from it's resting position to its highest position and then let go. There is no more external force applied, therefore no more work being done externally.

Since the pendulum is now swinging back and forth alternately between kinetic and potential energy is this work being done internally?

I understand that if kinetic energy is changing then work is being done. The pendulum is alternately producing kinetic and potential energy in which it is taking turns accelerating and decelerating as it swings back and forth.

So is this acceleration and deceleration between potential and kinetic energy work being done?

Comment: what about gravity?  Is this not a force still acting on the pendulum?

Comment: Yes, gravity is still a force acting on the pendulum, I would have added that into the question because I was trying to keep it simple, but yes that is the force that the kinetic and potential is alternately doing work with and against, so that would be an external force as well.

Answer (score 1):

Work is generally energy transferred into/out of a system. Energy changing *state* in a closed system isn't considered doing work.

Comment: Like the comment made above from ZeroTheHero, I didn't include gravity into the question when it probably should have been included. So there's still an external force involved. The question still stands though, is work still being done? Is it really a closed system with the internal 'changing state' of energy and the external force of gravity acting on the pendulum? Gravity accelerates the pendulum while the pendulum then alternately does work against the gravity and decelerates until the energy is exhausted. Why wouldn't this be considered work? Or is it?

Comment: Imagine the pendulum inside a sealed box. There is no energy in or out of the box so no 'work'. Enery is being exchanged between kinetic and potential but none (assuming no friction) is ever transferred out of the system

Comment: You said that work is 'generally' energy transferred into/out of a system. What does generally refer to?  What about the gravity though? Gravity is a force and force x distance is work. Isn't gravity doing work to pull the pendulum down and accelerate its velocity? Also isn't work being done again by swinging up and against gravity and decelerating it's velocity? So you're saying that the 'changing' kinetic energy isn't doing any work at all? Wouldn't gravity constitute an external force? Gravity can go through the sealed box, so wouldn't that be considered energy transfered out of the system?

Comment: 'generally' was scientific butt-covering in case there is some obscure area where 'work' is defined differently. Yes the pendulum does work against gravity on the way op and gets back that energy on the way down. Energy flows inside the system but not externally - work is the transfer in/out of the system

Comment: The general case makes sense. So the energy that flows inside the system would be only the mass of the pendulum itself as the working force doing the work against gravity, Yet the external force of gravity returns the energy to do work on the pendulum. So in a 'general' sense energy is flowing in and out of the 'closed' system, which apparently appears as an open system simultaneously. So far it seems that energy is flowing in and out of the system but doing work inside the system only, simultaneously with an existing external force, similar to the original force of lifting the pendulum up.